# How can use 'WHERE' with 'WhereNotIn' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to use `Where` to select `id` in some table which not in another table by `WhereNotIn`

```
 public function showbydate($id)
{

    $bookappoitm=DB::table('times')
         ->where('times.Dates_id','=',1)
         ->whereNOTIn('times.id',function($query){
               $query->select('times_id')->from('bookappoitments')
               ->where('users_id',Auth::user()->id);
         })
         ->get();

     return view('admin.Booking.addappointment', compact('bookappoitm'));
}
```

Ho can I use `$id` instead of number one '1'

Comment: just directly put it like this ->where('times.Dates_id',$id) i think. also you can remove "=" if nothing mention then it's default "="

Comment: thank you for your help but if I do that the query ignore WhereNotIn and select Where query ->where('times.Dates_id',$id)

Comment: one more thing put this whereNotIn to whereNoTIn there is capital T in not

Comment: public function showbydate($id)
    {
         
        

        $bookappoitm=DB::table('times')
       
      
              //->where('times.Dates_id',$id)

             ->where('times.Dates_id',$id)

                   
             ->whereNoTIn('times.id',function($query){

               $query->select('times_id')->from('bookappoitments')
              ->where('users_id',Auth::user()->id);
                               
        
         })
         
       ->get();

         return view('admin.Booking.addappointment', compact('bookappoitm'));
    }

Comment: Your T is in caps just lower that and try

Comment: use camel case like `whereNotIn`

Comment: thank you very much for your helping I found the problem the $id is coming  wrong http://127.0.0.1:8000/BookAppoint.showbydate/4     the number 4 not in my ids :(

Answer (score 0):

use this from Laravel doc:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                    ->get();
```

[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)